# SQL find all rows that do not have certain characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, database

I want to find all rows for which values in string column does not possess certain characters (to be specific [a-Z0-9 \t\n]) how can I do it in sql ?

I tried to do it with like operator

```
SELECT ***
where column like '%[^ a-Z0-9 \t\n]%'
```

however, it does not work and I get rows that possess characters and numbers.

Comment: add the DBMS tag please and add some sample data and the expected output

Comment: In SQL command use "!" instead of "^"."!" means "not" in SQL.
For example :
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerName LIKE '[!A-D]%'; - this will not return the CustomersName starts with A to D.

Comment: Use `%[^A-Za-z0-9 \t\n]%` instead

Answer (score 1):

To fetch all records that contain **any characters other than alphabets, numbers, spaces, tabs and new-line delimiters**:

```
SELECT ***
WHERE column like '%[^A-Za-z0-9 \t\n]%'
```

Note that `[^A-Za-z0-9 \t\n]` represents anything other than alphanumeric characters, spaces, tabs, and new line delimitters.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is inverted.  I think you want:

```
where column not like '%[^ a-Z0-9 \t\n]%'
```

I don't think that SQL Server interprets `\t` and `\n` as special characters.  You may need to insert the actual values for the characters.  (See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/char-transact-sql).)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ***
WHERE column like '%[^A-Za-z0-9 \t\n]%'
```

Comment: could you add more explanation to your answer please?